# How can I get a column from another table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, Clients and Documents.

Client's table is defined like:

```
ID   | NAME    | ADDRESS | TELEPHONE 
112  | EXAMPLE | ABC#123 | 85548484
115  | WOAH!   | ABC#123 | 85548484
```

and the Document's table is like:

```
ID|Number|ClientID|Total
1 | 363  |  112   | 25000
2 | 364  |  112   | 24000
3 | 365  |  115   | 21000
```

How can I get results like that without using an INNER JOIN?:

```
ID|Number|ClientID|Total| NAME    | ADDRESS | TELEPHONE 
1 | 363  |  112   |25000| EXAMPLE | ABC#123 | 85548484
2 | 364  |  112   |24000| EXAMPLE | ABC#123 | 85548484
3 | 365  |  115   |21000| WOAH!   | ABC#123 | 85548484
```

I tried

```
Select Documents.*, 
       (Select *from Clients where DOcuments.ClientID = Clients.ID ) 
FROM Documents
```

but I got wrong results..

Thank you!

Comment: What is wrong with an inner join?

Comment: The problem is when the ClientID is NULL, i don't got the row..

Comment: Even with _INNER JOIN_ you won't get that results if _ClientID IS NULL_

Comment: Do you want to join all rows with ClientID = NULL in Client table to all rows with ClientId = NULL in Document table?

Comment: Thank tou i solve the problem with outer apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply`:

```
select d.*, c.name, c.address, c.telephone
from documents d cross apply
     (select c.*
      from clients c
      where d.clientid = c.id
     ) c;
```

You could also use `left join`:

```
select d.*, c.name, c.address, c.telephone
from documents d left join
     clients c
     on d.clientid = c.id;
```

Or similar constructs using `full join` or `right join` or `outer apply`.  The restriction on `inner join` is quite curious.

EDIT:

If you want to keep all clients, even those with no documents:

```
select d.*, c.name, c.address, c.telephone
from clients c left join
     documents d
     on d.clientid = c.id;
```

Comment: the problem is when the ClientID from the document's table is NULL, the row is dissapear when it is null.. that is the problem.

Comment: @mdelphi . . . You have no example in your data where the id is null.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

select d.*, c.*
from documents d
left join clients c on c.clientId = d.clientId
-- add where clause and order by clause of your choosing